# C++ scoping rule clarification

Tags: c++, scoping

I just came across this:

```
    vector<int> vOut;

    for(int ui=0;ui<3;ui++)
    {
            vector<int> v;
            v.push_back(ui);
            vOut.push_back(ui);

            cerr << "v...";
            printVec(v);
            cerr << "vOut...";
            printVec(vOut);
    }
```

which produces the following output:

> v...Contents(Vector):0| vOut...Contents(Vector):0|
>
> v...Contents(Vector):1| vOut...Contents(Vector):0|1|
>
> v...Contents(Vector):2| vOut...Contents(Vector):0|1|2|

I thought that the lifetime of the vector was between the two { } in the loop, but it seems that I am wrong. For variables the lifetime is such that the value is not "forgotten" when re-iterating through the loop, and so it seems like this behaviour is very out-of-place.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: `vOut` wasn't declared in the brackets... I'm not sure I understand. That's the correct behavior. Things local to the brackets are destroyed at the end.

Comment: Vote to close as "head slap"? :}

Comment: As a counter-example:  for(int ui=0;ui<3;ui++)  { int i; if(ui == 0) i=0; i++; cerr << i << endl;}  This produces an ever-incrementing i ... Either I am re-using "dead" ram and relying on a side-effect, or this is different behaviour

Comment: @blah382 No, this produces **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Your counterexample is simply undefined behaviour, because you do not re-initialize the variable after it had gone out of scope and was the re-declared. It just so happens that it re-uses the same spot on the stack which still has the old value in it.

Comment: When you say, `I thought that the lifetime of the vector was between the two {}`, do you mean `vOut` or `v`?

Answer (score 1):

You can unroll the loop:

```
int ui=0;
{
    // code
}
ui++;
{
    // code
}
ui++;
{
    // code
}
ui++;
```

When you look at this code, it should become clear why the local variables behave like they do.